# IPv6 default route is removed after net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding is set to 1

Tags: ubuntu, ipv6

I see the ipv6 default router is gone when I set my ubuntu VM to forwarding IPv6 packet.

Below is the snippet when I spin up my ubuntu VM:

```
tester@myubuntu:~$ ip -6 route
2001:420:293:242d::/64 dev ens192 proto kernel metric 256 expires 2591987sec pref medium
fe80::/64 dev ens192 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
default via fe80::76a2:e6ff:fec6:2bff dev ens192 proto ra metric 1024 expires 1787sec hoplimit 64 pref medium
default via fe80::76a2:e6ff:fec6:2e3f dev ens192 proto ra metric 1024 expires 1777sec hoplimit 64 pref medium
```

When I set the forwarding flag to 1:

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
```

The VM v6 default router is gone:

```
 tester@myubuntu:~$ ip -6 route
2001:420:293:242d::/64 dev ens192 proto kernel metric 256 expires 2591987sec pref medium
fe80::/64 dev ens192 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
```

I also set  sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra=2 and it doesn't seem help.

Just wonder if I have missed some setup?

Comment: In which order did you set the sysctls? It is important.

Comment: I tried both order (accept_ra first and the forwarding, or vice versa), same behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the note about accept_ra=2, this solved the issue in the title for me, but only when I applied it to a single network interface (ie not "conf.all" but "conf.eth0")

Comment: Hey @Kintarō, I encounter the same issue as you on an AWS EC2, with an AL2 AMI. Just as you mentioned,  setting `net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra=2` before enabling forwarding does not help. Same after rebooting. Have you eventually found the issue to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have the following in my /etc/sysctl.conf:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
net.ipv6.conf.enp4s0/666.accept_ra = 2
```

And it works fine (Debian 9 router here).

Perhaps a dumb question - did you reboot ?  I've noticed certain IPv6 bits in the kernel don't like to change with just a sysctl on a running machine, and a reboot clears it up.